# Group by a column and select the group id on condition that applies to all the rows in it

Tags: sql-server, group-by, where

I have the below table

```
CREATE TABLE result(
   id    INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,cid   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,aid   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,agid  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,ft    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,ct    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,jid   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,fcn   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,iap   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,flags INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,afcf  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (44,2,9,6,2,1698222904,52,-1,1,65536,65539);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (44,2,9,6,2,1698222904,52,-1,2,65536,4099);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (54,2,9,6,2,1698223114,56,-1,1,65536,65539);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (54,2,9,6,2,1698223114,56,-1,2,65536,4099);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (68,2,9,6,2,1698223386,59,-1,1,65536,3);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (68,2,9,6,2,1698223386,59,-1,2,65536,4099);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (80,2,9,6,2,1698223477,60,-1,1,65536,3);
INSERT INTO result(id,cid,aid,agid,ft,ct,jid,fcn,iap,flags,afcf) VALUES (80,2,9,6,2,1698223477,60,-1,2,65536,4099);
```

The values looks like

| id | cid | aid | agid | ft | ct | jid | fcn | iap | flags | afcf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698222904 | 52 | -1 | 1 | 65536 | 65539 |
| 44 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698222904 | 52 | -1 | 2 | 65536 | 4099 |
| 54 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698223114 | 56 | -1 | 1 | 65536 | 65539 |
| 54 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698223114 | 56 | -1 | 2 | 65536 | 4099 |
| 68 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698223386 | 59 | -1 | 1 | 65536 | 3 |
| 68 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698223386 | 59 | -1 | 2 | 65536 | 4099 |
| 80 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698223477 | 60 | -1 | 1 | 65536 | 3 |
| 80 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 1698223477 | 60 | -1 | 2 | 65536 | 4099 |

In the above table for each of the group iap whose value here is `[1,2]`. I want to get that iap where `afcf & 65536 = 0` else I want the value to be `NULL`.

So my output would contain `2` for above table as all the rows in iap 2 satisfy the condition `afcf & 65536 = 0.

**What needs to be done**

For each of the group of iap, check if all its rows satisfies the condition `afcf & 65536 = 0` if yes then print that group id `iap`.

**Expected Output**

Since iap = [2] satisfied above condition for all of its rows

```
2
```

This is what I tried, which is wrong.

```
SELECT iap FROM result
GROUP BY iap
HAVING afcf & 65536 = 0
```

Comment: The test data in your question has duplicate primary key values.

Comment: *`HAVING afcf & 65536 = 0`* ??? You do not apply aggregate function. 4 rows in a group (GROUP BY iap) have different values in this column (65539 AND 3) - what of them you want to be tested with your condition?

Comment: @Akina i told you the query is wrong, I want to do something like above which gives the group id iap

Comment: @DanGuzman that was a mistake, edited!

Comment: I cannot understand your question completely. Show desired output for shown data, and add detailed explanations.

Comment: @Akina check my edited answer

Comment: @Akina I believe OP wants all rows in the grouping to satisfy the condition: "*So my output would contain 2 for above table as **all the rows** in iap 2 satisfy the condition."*

Answer (score 0):

> my output would contain 2 for above table as all the rows in iap 2 satisfy the condition `afcf & 65536 = 0`.

For example, this may be

```
SELECT iap 
FROM result
GROUP BY iap
HAVING MAX(afcf & 65536) = 0
```

But I'd use

```
SELECT iap 
FROM result
GROUP BY iap
HAVING MAX(afcf) < 65536
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/zPGhVZMY